# How to get CakePHP's migration plugin to work under windows?

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I have a running CakePHP 1.3 site under Windows using ZendServer CE. I have also added win-bash and such in my Path. Console seems to work fine, except when trying to use the migration plugin. Seems no matter what I try i get:

"Error: Class MigrationShell could not be loaded."

Anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had similar issue for one of our dev setups for windows. The trick is to run the migrations commands from the root folder of your application - that is the folder that contains "app", "cake" etc. folders

Once you **cd** into your root folder - run **php cake/console/cake.php migration all**